# Fontconfig question about font substitution order

Tags: xorg, fontconfig

Let me ask using an example.

A web browser or other application may declare or set to use Arial font. Then the actual user content in the application is in Chinese. My system has Arial font and other two Chinese fonts installed, "WenQuanYi Zen Hei" and "Noto Sans CJK SC".

My question is, how can I ensure the fontconfig to always choose "Noto Sans CJK SC" to a reader the user content in this case?

I know a little about `fc-match -s` command, I am guessing, if the Noto appeared before WenQuanYi, then my wish will be fulfilled. Is that right? If so, I still have no idea how to config/change the order the fonts name in the output of the fc-match command.

Thanks in advance.

-woody

Answer (score 1):

You can have an unconditional prepending match in your `fonts.conf`, for example:

```
<fontconfig>
    <match>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend_first" binding="strong">
            <string>xos4 Terminus</string>
            <string>Fixed</string>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

You can read `man fonts.conf` for configuring a more complex font selection algorithm.